# No Factory Reset Option

Tags: windows-8.1, factory-defaults

I wish to Factory Reset my Windows 8.1 HP Laptop. However, in the recovery window of settings, the only option is Advanced Setup and there is no Refresh or Factory Reset Option. So, how to I factory reset?

Comment: Are you wanting to do a refresh without affecting any of your files, or are you wanting to do a refresh where you completely wipe everything?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Settings - Change PC-Settings

2 - Update and Recovery - Recovery

3 - Remove everything and reinstall Windows - Get started

4 - (or this for refresh) Refresh your PC without affecting your files - Get 
    started

You might also try to boot up with the original Windows8.1 DVD or with "F6" or "F8" and choose automatic Repair-mode and search for the settings.